# Grammar with since as a conjunction

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, verb-agreement

**Which** one **is correct** between the two given sentences and **why**?

1) It **is** five years since I saw a movie.

2) It **has been** five years since I saw a movie.

Comment: Both are grammatical.

Comment: I always use present perfect with that: It's been five years since etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your verb **saw** is in the past tense but **is** is in the present tense, so therefore this would be correct:

> It **has been** five years since I saw a movie

As has **been** is in the past tense

Answer (score 1):

Use:

> It **has been** five years since I saw a movie.

It describes a period of time between 5 years ago and the time of the statement (now). So it is correct to use present perfect *has been*.